# Boxing and Unboxing

Tags: c#, value-type, boxing

I have a small doubt regarding Boxing and Unboxing in C#.

```
int i=1;
System.Int32 j = i;
```

above code can be called as boxing?

Comment: Thank you bhava, kalale aata.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's not boxing at all. `int` is *just* an alias for `System.Int32`. That code is equivalent to:

```
int i = 1;
int j = i;
```

For boxing to occur, there has to be a conversion to a reference type, e.g.

```
int i = 1;
object j = i;
```

Or:

```
int i = 1;
IComparable j = i;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to extend Jon's answer just a little bit, boxing will also occur, when you call non-overridden or non-virtual methods of the base class also, like

```
i.GetType(); //boxing occur here
```

or pass `int` to a method, which requires a reference type

```
void Foo(object obj) {}

Foo(i); //boxing, no overload takes an int
```

In the first example `IL` you can clearly see `box` instruction

```
int i = 5;
i.GetType();

IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0002:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0003:  box         System.Int32    //<---- boxing
IL_0008:  call        System.Object.GetType
```

If you don't override virtual methods in your value types, they will also be boxed when calling them

```
enum MyEnum {}

var e = new MyEnum();
e.ToString(); //box will occur here, see IL for details

IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // e
IL_0002:  ldloc.0     // e
IL_0003:  box         UserQuery.MyEnum
IL_0008:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
```

The same situations with structs, except they will use `callvirt` opcode, that will box the struct if nessecary,

Answer (score 0):

No. int is a value type.

Boxing occurs when you assign a value type to an Object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *boxing*.

`int` is an alias for `System.Int32`. So your code is equavalent to;

```
int i = 1;
int j = i;
```

For boxing, there should be a conversion to an *object* or an interface. Like;

```
int i = 1;
object j = i;
```

> A value of a class type can be converted to type object or to an
>   interface type that is implemented by the class simply by treating the
>   reference as another type at compile-time. Likewise, a value of type
>   object or a value of an interface type can be converted back to a
>   class type without changing the reference (but of course a run-time
>   type check is required in this case).

- [`Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [`Boxing and unboxing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)